# Dynamic variables in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have code that look like this

```
(defun work ()
  (interactive)
  (case major-mode
    ('javascript-mode (setq js-indent-level (if (eq js-indent-level 2) 4 2)))
    ('css-mode (setq cssm-indent-level (if (eq cssm-indent-level 2) 4 2)))
    ('nxml-mode (setq nxml-child-indent (if (eq nxml-child-indent 2) 4 2)))
    (t (setq c-basic-offset (if (eq c-basic-offset 2) 4 2)))))
```

that switch between indent level of 2 and 4 (I use 4 indent spaces but need 2 for work), is it posibble to shrink that code every line look the same to something like:

```
(defun work ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((var (case major-mode
                 ('javascript-mode 'js-indent-level)
                 ('css-mode 'cssm-indent-level)
                 ('nxml-mode 'nxml-child-indent)
                 (t 'c-basic-offset))))
     ;; like C pointers
     (setf (pointer var) (if (eq (pointer var) 2) 4 2))))
```

or

```
(defun work ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((var (cdr (assoc major-mode indent-vars))))
     (setf (pointer var) (if (eq (pointer var) 2) 4 2))))
```

if I have my indent variables in indent-vars alist

do I need to use macro or eval do do that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use file- or directory-local variables for this?

Comment: @immerrr what are those?

Comment: `M-:(info "(emacs) File Variables")` and `M-:(info "(emacs) Directory Variables")` give a good survey. (Press `M-:` and then copy paste the command from here. Afterwards press `enter`. You are directly lead to the right info node.)

Comment: @Tobias, another way of looking this up in the manual is `C-h r m "File Variables"` and `C-h r m "Directory Variables"` with a bonus of TAB-completion :)

Comment: @Tobias I don't understand how Local Variables can help here.

Comment: I also think that they are of limited help. You could put `((js-indent-level 2) (cssm-indent-level 2) (nxml-child-indent 2))` into the file `.dir-locals.el` in your project directories at work. But, I think if you have many projects that is not an option. From my point of view you have to specify it in your initialization file.

Comment: @Tobias I have one directory but with lots of sub directories. It's SVN repo.

Comment: @jcubic: I know. I would also not use file or directory local variables for this purpose. Note, that the proposal about file-or directory-local variables came from immerrr. I just wanted to give the link to the description to those variables because you asked.

Comment: @jcubic, number of sub-directories doesn't matter, `.dir-locals.el` is being looked up in directory hierarchy, starting from the directory of current file. So, if you put it to root directory of repository "checkout" you'll have your variables in all files in this "checkout". As long as you don't have many "checkouts" of same/similar repositories, you're good, which was exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: @immerrr I used `project-specifics` macro from http://whattheemacsd.com

Comment: `(case foo ('a toto))` returns `toto` if `foo` has value `a` or `quote`.  IOW the quote in front of `a` does not do what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [symbol-value](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbols.html) and [`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Variables.html).

```
(defun work ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((var (cdr (assoc major-mode indent-vars))))
     (set var (if (eq (symbol-value var) 2) 4 2))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following instead of the `setf`-construct.

```
(set var (if (eq (eval var) 2) 4 2))
```

It should work but I did not test it.